# Function called but without reference to parameter

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code and something strange happens. The last line `fizzbuzz(15)` where I call the function is necessary to get the loop to run, but does not take into account the parameter, in this case, 15. How can I integrate the parameter into my function?

```
function fizzbuzz(num) {

    for(num = 0; num < 20; num++) {


        if(num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 === 0){
            result = "fizzbuzz";
        }

        else if(num % 3 === 0){
            result = "fizz";
        }

        else if(num % 5 === 0){
            result = "buzz";
        }

        else if(num % 3 !==0 && num % 5 !==0){
            result = num;
        }

        console.log(result);
    }


}

fizzbuzz(15);
```

Comment: `num = 0;` sets the `num` parameter back to `0`.

Comment: @CodeYogi don't take this the wrong way, but if you aren't familiar with your browser's debugging tools, they can be a big help when troubleshooting an issue with scripts doing something other than expected, especially when they're not throwing any errors. Here are help pages for Firefox and Chrome, but almost every modern browser on desktop/PC has a similar set of tools.
FF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/

Answer (score 2):

```
for(num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
```

You're changing it back to `0` here every time you run this. It doesn't matter what you pass in if you keep assigning zero.

I suppose this is what you're after:

```
for(num; num < 20; num++) {
```

Or, if you are after setting the number of iterations, then this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
```

(and then change all of your references inside of the loop from `num` to the more idiomatic `i`)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I thought that the initial parameter describes where the loop starts. So, I thought that starting at 0, would run the loop on every number from zero up until 20?

Comment: @CodeYogi yes that's exactly what it's for. But you are using the same variable name as your function argument (`num`) so you are overwriting what you're passing in.

Comment: Your job this time will be to write a function called fizzbuzz that takes a parameter num; for every number from 1 to num, this function should print (using console.log()) one of the following values:

'fizz' if the number is divisible by 3 (but not 5)
'buzz' if the number is divisible by 5 (but not 3)
'fizzbuzz' if the number is divisible by both 3 and 5
the number itself if it isn't divisible by either 3 or 5
For reference, running fizzbuzz(15) should result in the following text being printed in the console:

1
2
fizz
4
buzz
fizz
7
8
fizz
buzz
11
fizz
13
14
fizzbuzz

Comment: Ok, I see, the variable and the function must have different names...thanks. I'm obviously new at this!